# Get the ID of an sql row when created, instantly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

So I have a recyclerView that you can add objects to. These objects are saved in an sql database, therefore they each have their own unique ids. I need to pass the id of an object clicked into the next activity.

My problem is that when the recyclerView populates with an object just added, the id is always 0 unless I refresh the activity, then the id gets populated correctly. I would like to get the id as soon as the object is created / added. I have an idea, and that is when creating the object, to set the id myself, but I'm not sure how to do that, or if it's the right way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert into the database, if you use the [insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) convenience method, it returns the [**rowid**](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) of the inserted row as a long, which will be the same as value for a column that aliases the **rowid**. Specifically using `column INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (with or without AUTOINCREMENT) makes the column an alias of the **rowid**.

As such get the value returned, and that's the id (typically if you take advantage of this feature of SQLite and the Android SDK).

Comment: Thanks. Before I saw this, I ended up making another variable that gets set as a random number when the object is created. I then just pass this unique number over. Is this a terrible way of doing it? Should I change?

Comment: @tbunreal the problem with that method is if you generate an already used value and the column is UNIQUE (explicitly or implicity (e.g. alias of rowid is implicitly UNIQUE)), then the insert will either fail or not insert the data (the insert convenience method effectively uses INSERT OR IGNORE so no failure but no insert (returns -1)). It's not terrible, but better (and more efficient) to let SQLite do what it is good at. (if the column is not UNIQUE then you could end up indavertently updating the wrong rows).

Answer (score 0):

Here is fully fledged code I guarantee that it would solve your doubt,in android we do not have to mention the id while inserting data to the database table,id is by default same as the order of the data in the table ie if the data is at the 1st place in the table ,then it

```
 package com.example.elavi.databasedemo;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Users", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(name VARCHAR,age INT(3),id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO users(name,age) VALUES('Lavish',20)");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO users(name,age)VALUES('Saina',24)");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO users(name,age)VALUES('Saina',55)");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO users(name,age)VALUES('Sourabh',75)");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO users(name,age)VALUES('Suresh',30)");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO users(name,age)VALUES('Dog',49)");
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM users WHERE name='Sourabh'");
            Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT*FROM users ", null);
            int nameindex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
            int rowindex = c.getColumnIndex("age");
            int idindex=c.getColumnIndex("id");
            c.moveToFirst();
            while (c != null) {
                Log.i("Name is ", c.getString(nameindex));
                Log.i("Age is", c.getString(rowindex));
                Log.i("Id is", c.getString(idindex));
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**do ask if you any doubt**